# devicetree wildcard for delete-node

Tags: wildcard, device-tree

I have some devicetree files that are autogenerated from a tool (Vivado/Petalinux).  In a "user" dtsi file, I make some modifications but I have a question about deleting nodes that do not have a label but are explicitly called out with their physical address.  As the exact physical address is not necessarily  known to the "user", a wildcard would be nice.

From the generated file (pl.dtsi):

```
axi_ethernet_0_dma: dma@40400000 {
    //et cetera;
    dma-channel@40400000 {
        //et cetera;
    };
    dma-channel@40400030 {
        //et cetera;
    };
};
```

In a user dtsi (system-user.dtsi):

```
{
};

&axi_ethernet_0_dma {
    /delete-node/ dma-channel@40400000;
    /delete-node/ dma-channel@40400030;
};
```

Obviously, prior knowledge of the physical addresses is required to delete the nodes.

Is there a way to wildcard this so I could do something like:

```
&axi_ethernet_0_dma {
    /delete-node/ dma-channel*
};
```

Comment: *"Handle"*???  There is no such entity in the [DT specification](https://www.devicetree.org/specifications/).  Do you mean a phandle or a label?

Comment: Label, I presume - edited.  Do you happen to have a solution?